# � exists in my markdown files strangely

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

I have a markdown written in Chinese. my local file seems fine but there are some � characters in it when I upload it to GitHub. see the following pics

[image: local file]

[image: mygithub]

Comment: I have reedited it on GitHub,but I'm curious about why this is happening,my vs-code encoding is utf-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all right,figure it out.

I Inserted some control characters by mistake and the vs-code hided control characters by default.

just press cmd+shift+p to toggle control characters.then delete the control characters.

Answer (score 0):

The "� " character is a placeholder in unicode for characters it does not recognize.

Your copy of visual studio is using a font that contains those characters, so it does not have the placeholder. Your browser is using a font that does *not* contain those characters, so the placeholder gets displayed.

To fix this, you should select a font for your browser that has those characters, such as the one your copy of Visual Studio is using.

Comment: except to change my browser font, Can I change the vscode font.
my vscode font family is :"editor.fontFamily": "Menlo, Monaco, 'Courier New', monospace",